# Detect when iOS stops my recording

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, recording, audioqueueservices

I'm using Audio Queue Services on iOS to make an app that records, even when the phone is locked or the app isn't in the foreground. This much I have working.

However, if I open Safari and play audio or open another recording app like Voice Memo and press record, the recording on my app will stop. This makes sense, but how can I detect when it has happened?

I've tried something like:

```
UInt32 running;
UInt32 size = 4;
AudioQueueGetProperty(recordState.queue, kAudioQueueProperty_IsRunning, &running, &size);
return running;
```

but this always returns true once I have started the recording in my app, even if iOS has stopped my background recording to make way for audio in some other application.